# Linked List and Pointers Pointing correctly?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

```
struct my_struct
{
    struct my_struct *next;
    int data;
};

struct my_struct *root;
```

Then if I want to do something like find the struct in the linked list with the highest data value should I use my pointers like this?

```
struct my_struct *temp = head;
struct my_struct *highest = head;

for(I = 0; I<10; I++)
{
  temp = temp->next;
}
```

So my main question is: should it be `temp = temp->next;` or should it be temp = address of temp->next, `temp = &temp->next;` or should it be `temp = *temp->next;` and the logic behind it would help me a lot.

Comment: Try all these variants and see which ones the compiler is happy with. Is there more than one?

Comment: Compiler seems to be happy with the one I wrote in the code block. temp = temp->next; I would like to know though and although I been reading most of the posts here I still don't get it. I mean I know what & does and *pointer mean but I am still lost.

Comment: Step through the code with a debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `temp = temp->next;`

In c, the syntax `temp->next` is equivalent to `(*temp).next`.  In other words, it dereferences the pointer `temp` and extracts the `next` attribute.  You have defined the `next` attribute as a `my_struct*` (pointer to a `my_struct`). This is the same data type as `temp`, so the assignment works.

Also, I wouldn't recommend using a `for` loop with a fixed iteration limit--not unless you already know that the list will only ever have at most 10 elements.  And in that case, why not use an array?

Try a loop like this:

```
struct my_struct* temp = head;
struct my_struct* highest = null;
int highestFound = -1; // or some other value known to be below all values in the list
while (temp != null) {
    if(temp->data > highestFound) {
        highestFound = temp->data;
        highest = temp;
    }
    temp = temp->next;
}
```